# Stream rtsp ip camera to website

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

My question is related to streaming of an ip cam with rtsp on my website. The rtsp link I have is something like this (for obvious reasons I can't share the real one) rtsp://test.ddns.net:4000/profile2.

I tried to display it on my website using embedded code but I can't find one, or didn't work on some browsers or didn't work at all. So I'm asking if someone had same problem here and how to make it work on all browsers, possibly without using plugins for browsers.

P.s. i read a lot of forums these days and if possible I want to achieve that without using wowza or other services.

Some examples of code I used:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
        codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
        width="640" height="496">
        <param name="src" value="sample-movie.qtl" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
        <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
        <!--[if !IE]> <-->
        <object data="sample-movie.qtl" width="640" height="496" type="video/quicktime">
            <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
        </object>
        <!--> <![endif]-->
    </object>
```

with sample-movie.qtl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?quicktime type="application/x-quicktime-media-link"?>
<embed
autoplay="true"
fullscreen="full"
href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"
src="rtsp://test.ddns.net:4000/profile2"
/>
```

And I also tried VLC code:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
 codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
 width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
<param name="Src" value="rtsp://cameraipaddress" />
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
<param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
<param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
<embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="480"
 target="rtsp://cameraipaddress" ></embed>
</OBJECT>
```

But still no solution fits all browsers, vlc code doesn't even show the image of the cam. For now the ony solution that partially works is the quicktime one, but only on firefox for window and IE.

Sorry for the long post, but I hope someone can help me understand better the streaming and rtsp protocol and hopefully help me find a solution.

Regards,
Aleksander

Answer (score 1):

2020 update - you have two main options, depending on required latency:

1. latency of 10-30 seconds. Use some application that receives RTSP stream and converts it to HLS. ffmpeg is an obvious free choice; most free and commercial media servers will do it too.
2. Near-real-time: latency below 1 second: use WebRTC and you have two ways to go:

   - Install on-premise media server software that will convert RTSP to WebRTC: there are
     free and commercial options; try Ant Media Server, Unreal Media Server, Kurento.
   - Use WebRTC clouds like Millicast or Phenix.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert server side to something more browsers support, like MSE. using wowza or red5 to do the conversion is probably the easiest route.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in other way without using wowza or red5?

Comment: ffmpeg + nginx. And many more. If you are asking if you can have the browser play rtsp with a server component. the answer is no.